# Perl: How to get the list variables that have been used in session file

Tags: perl

At my workplace we have a webportal that has some core files through which other files are called. So there are some variables for username and project id that everyone uses and are defined in core file. Now I have to avoid using the use strict for using the same variable but i don't want to do it. So how can I get the list of variables that were in the core file? or in basic case how can I get the value in some variable $projectId while using strict.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any variable that is not declared and lexically scoped with `my` is a package variable. You can refer to a package variable without `strict` complaining by qualifying the variable name with the package. So if the "core file" defines a variable `$projectid` in the default `main` package, you can safely refer to it with

```
$main::projectid
$::projectid         ($::foo  is the same thing as $main::foo)
```

or if the "core file" contains a `package` statement like `package ProjectData;`, then you would use

```
$ProjectData::projectid
```

If the global variable is from the current package (e.g., both the core file and your script are using the default package), then you could also satisfy `strict` by declaring the variable with the `our` keyword.

```
package main;
our $projectid;
# now  $projectid  refers to $main::projectid
...
```